# Update a table using sum of values from another table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Could someone please help me with this?
I want to update `tblTotals` using `Sum` of `Cost` from `tblAppointments`. I have:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
Dim rs1 As DAO. Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO. Recordset

Set rs1 =  CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Pets, Sum(cost) As TotalCost FROM tblAppointments WHERE (((DateDiff('m',[AppointmentDate],DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1))) Between -6 And 5)) GROUP BY Pets")

Set rs2 = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Pets, TotalCost FROM tblTotals")

With rs1
If Not rs1.BOF then rs1.Movefirst 
Do Until r1.EOF
rs2. Edit
rs2.Fields("TotalCost").Value = rs1.Fields("TotalCost").Value
rs2.Update
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
End With 


End Sub
```

`tblTotals`

```
+=========+=========+=============+
+  Pets   +    Dr   +  TotalCost  +
+=========+=========+=============+
+  Cats   +   John  +  £20.00     +
+---------+---------+-------------+ 
+  Dogs   +   Sam   +  £80.00     +
+---------+---------+-------------+ 
+  Rabits +   Ellis +  £85.35     +
+---------+---------+-------------+
+ Parrots +   Ellis +  £63.00     +
+---------+---------+-------------+`
```

`tblAppointments:`

```
+=========+=========+=============+=================+
+  Pets   +    Dr   +   Cost      + AppointmentDate +
+=========+=========+=============+==================
+  Cats   +   John  +  20.50      + 12/02/2020      +
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+
+  Dogs   +   Sam   +  80.00      + 10/05/2020      +
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+ 
+  Dogs   +   Sam   +  80.00      + 12/02/2020      +
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+ 
+  Rabits +  Ellis  +  £85.35     + 12/12/2019      +
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+ 
+  Cats   +  John   +  20.50      + 12/10/2019      +
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+ 
+  Cats   +  John   +  20.50      + 12/09/2019      +
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+ 
+ Parrots +  Ellis  +  £63.25     + 12/08/2019      +
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+`
```

Expected results:

`tblTotals`

```
+=========+=========+=============+
+  Pets   +    Dr   +  TotalCost  +
+=========+=========+=============+
+  Cats   +   John  +  £61.50     +
+---------+---------+-------------+ 
+  Dogs   +   Sam   +  £160.00    +
+---------+---------+-------------+ 
+  Rabits +   Ellis +  £85.35     +
+---------+---------+-------------+
+ Parrots +   Ellis +  £63.00     +
+---------+---------+-------------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE using an aggregate query is not possible. Aggregate value should not be saved, calculate when needed. If it can be calculated for update then just use the SELECT query with the calculation. SELECT queries are not executed anyway, only action SQL are (DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT). Saving this aggregate calc would require looping through recordset and saving value one record at a time.

Comment: @June7 is there another way of getting around this? How about the use of DSum and other built-in functions?

Comment: Yes, can use DSum. Domain aggregate functions can perform slowly in large dataset. Or  loop through recordset and save value one record at a time. Could also DELETE all records and INSERT a complete new set. Saving this data is usually unnecessary and often bad design.

Comment: @June7 how would one go on by inserting a new set from aggregate query?

Comment: Explore INSERT INTO SELECT action. Kind of what you were trying with your UPDATE which was improper syntax.

Comment: @June7 I have realised that it's not an option to delete and insert due to bad design. I have explored the recordset method. Please see updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you have no good choices but to try and come up with a solution despite poor design. In this case. I used `DAO` to `Update` `tblTotals` using an aggregate query as a `recordset`. As long as the tables in question are of a fairly small size, you should not notice any significant speed issues.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()

Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set rs1 =  CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Pets, Sum(Cost) As TotalCost FROM tblAppointments WHERE (((DateDiff('m',[AppointmentDate],DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1))) Between -6 And 5)) GROUP BY Pets")

Set rs2 = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Pets, TotalCost FROM tblTotals")


rs1.MoveFirst
Do Until rs1.EOF
rs2.MoveFirst
Do Until rs2.EOF
If rs1![Pets] = rs2![Pets] Then
rs2.Edit
rs2.Fields("TotalCost").Value = rs1.Fields("TotalCost").Value
rs2.Update
End If
rs2.MoveNext
Loop
rs1.MoveNext
Loop

rs1.Close
rs2.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @June7 it needs until the next day otherwise would have done it already.